# CORS Ajax request from a flat HTML file with cookies

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, cors

I am trying to make a stand-alone HTML file that makes cross-domain requests via CORS to a RESTful JSON service.

My jQuery ajax request:

```
var query = $.ajax(
{
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8626/Home/About',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response)
    {
        alert('success');
        alert(query.getAllResponseHeaders());
        alert($.cookie('SessionID'));
    },
    error: function (x, e)
    {
        alert('error ' + e);
    }
});
```

I set the Access-Control-etc headers on the (ASP MVC3) server side:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE");

    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

    Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("SessionID", "1234"));

    return Json(new { name = "John" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Apart from cookies, everything works well. I get my response JSON data properly.

But I am also sending a cookie back from the server. It isn't showing in the headers as a Set-Cookie, and it isn't showing in the cookies collection. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863571/cors-request-why-are-the-cookies-not-sent) that to get cookies in a cross-domain request, you need to set the following in the $.ajax call:

```
xhrFields:
{
    withCredentials: true
},
```

When I add this, the call no longer works, with a JS error:

```
Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.
```

Clearly it is griping about my Access-Control-Allow-Origin header being "*".

Since this is a flat, stand-alone HTML file (sourced from the disk, not from an HTTP server), Chrome is passing along an Origin header equal to "null". I don't appear to be able to override this value -- when I add a custom Origin header, Chrome apparently disregards it.

If I return Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "null" (matching the Origin header value from the request), I get the JS error:

```
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So I don't know what to do. I can't get my cookies with the wildcard, and allowing "null" instead doesn't work either.

Is this not possible? Or am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

Your server needs to allow credentials with this header.

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Answer (score 0):

Try to put you page on-site and access it via network (you can mount it into a local web server).

If you just want to test it on Chrome - there's a Chrome startup flag called `--disable-web-security`.

This link is about how to launch Chrome with parameters:
http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags.