# Why the cookie I set with PHP cannot be read with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, cors

I'm trying to set a cookie from a extern php in my website. I found this question, but its still unresolved [Set-Cookie on Browser with Ajax Request via CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221722/set-cookie-on-browser-with-ajax-request-via-cors)

Basically my php looks like this.

```
<?php

ob_start();

setcookie("cookiename", "cookiedata", time() + 10000000, '/', false, false);

ob_end_flush();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  

?>
```

The header response is like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    *
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Wed, 01 Oct 2014 20:53:51 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
Set-Cookie  cookiename=cookiedata; expires=Sun, 25-Jan-2015 14:40:31 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.7
```

I can't see the cookie in the firebug tab (neither with other browser debuggers). When I console.log() all the cookies in javascript it does not appear either. So I don't know if someone can guide me through this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and prints out the cookie:

```
<?php

ob_start();

setcookie("cookiename", "cookiedata", time() + 10000000, '/', false, false);

ob_end_flush();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  

?>

All cookies: <p id="cookies"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = document.cookie;
</script>
```

Or are you requesting the URL via AJAX and expecting to read the cookies in document.cookie run in the parent document?

Comment: Mmm yeah I should have mentioned that, I'm calling the php with the jquery.form.js plugin, so I can make an ajax call with ie8-9 with php. I can't set cookies with an ajax call ?