# Assign cookie from controller to external html file

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm using `.NET CORE 1.1.0` was able to assign and read cookies from the `middleware` as:

```
app.Run(async context =>
{
    context.Response.Cookies.Append("se_id","5");
    Console.WriteLine(context.Request.Cookies["se_id"]);

    await _next.Invoke(context);  
});
```

But when I tried to do the same from the `Controller` I did not get anything done, the cookie is neither written nor is read.

I tried in the controller to use the below as well, but did not work:

```
namespace ApiCall.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class FetchController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Post([FromBody]object loginParam)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Append("id2","8");
            Console.WriteLine(Request.Cookies["se_id"]);

        }
    }
}
```

What is the difference between handling the cookie in the `middleware` and handling it in the `controller`

**UPDATE**

I updated my code based on the feedback given in the comments, I noticed the below:
1. The controller is writing to the request that is coming from the server.
2. The controller did not write to the request that is coming from `External` file

the updated code I've is:

`controller.cs`:

```
using System;    // for Console.WriteLine
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;  // for Controller, [Route], [HttpPost], [FromBody], JsonResult and Json

namespace server
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ResinsController : Controller{

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get(){
           #region
              var result = new List<Item>();
              result.Add(new Item{Code = "320"});
           #endregion
         Response.Cookies.Append("id2", "8");
         Console.WriteLine(Request.Cookies["id2"]);
         return Json(result);
        }
    }

    public class Item{
        public string Code { get; set; }
   }
}
```

The above code is working fine, once I call it from `http://localhost:60000/api/Resins`

But not working when I call it from external file, the external file is working file in terms of `fetch` as I received the returned value, and can see it in the concole, what is not working is handling the `cookies`, my `index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Test page for using ajax call in webapi core.
    </h2>
    <button onclick="useFetch()">Use Fetch</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function useFetch() {
            fetch('http://localhost:60000/api/Resins', {
                method: 'get'
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(returnedValue) {
                var value = returnedValue;
                console.log(value);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>                                           
</html>
```

if required, the `program.cs` file is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;  // for WebHostBuilder()

namespace server{
    public class Program{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            #region Define Host
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:60000", "https://localhost:60001")
                .UseStartup<Startup>()   // Startup is the class name, not the file name
                .Build();
            #endregion

        host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

the `startup.cs` file is:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;  // for IServiceCollection
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;   // for IApplicationBuilder and FileServerOptions
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;  // for IHostingEnvironment

namespace server{
    public class Startup{
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
            services.AddCors();  // to be accesssed from external sites, i.e. outside the server
            services.AddMvc();   // to use Controllers, Add framework services.
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env){
            app.UseCors(builder =>   // to be accesssed from external sites, i.e. outside the server
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .AllowCredentials()
                        );
            app.UseMvc();          
        }
    }
}
```

and the `project.json` file is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

While checking the different screens in the `browser developer tool`, I found the attached:
1. The `Application` screen mention clearly there are no cookies,
2. The `Network` -> `Cookies` screen shos the cookie had been written correctly, but the controller can not read it back, which means the controller trying to read the cookie from the `Application cookies` not from the `Network cookies`

[image]

Comment: Aren't you just using a different id (**id2** vs **se_id**), or is it just a typo in the question? Have you checked the response headers sent to the browser/fiddle/whatever? I tried 1.1 and had no trouble setting cookies in a controller using `Response.Cookies.Append` the same way you did

Comment: @DanielJ.G. it is not typo, I just tried creating agitato cookie and read the old one, I could not read the already made one, and could not create new one,  I checked in the browser developer tool, the 'id2' cookie, never got create, can you please share with me your test file that worked with you, as zip folder, so I look into it, may it help figuring something wrong somewhere. Thanks

Comment: I created a new project in VS, upgraded to 1.1 and used pretty much your controller. Check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DaniJG/ac1e54579985efe96718fc70b0f1a069)

Comment: Thanks @DanielJ.G. Kindly see my update to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found guidelines from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667723/2441637), where the issue looks to be related to the request in the external html file, not to the controller programming, and as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials):

> [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) responses from a different domain cannot set [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) values for their own domain unless withCredentials is set to true before making the request, regardless of Access-Control- header values

In my code, it worked after adding the `credentials: 'include'` to the [fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) so my original code became like:

```
fetch('http://localhost:60000/api/Resins', {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'get'
}).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
}).then(function(returnedValue) {
      var asdf = returnedValue;
      console.log(asdf);
}).catch(function (err) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

and cookies can now be read from the controller, though in the browser developer tool, still can be seen under `network -> Cookies` and nothing appearing under `Application -> cookies`.

[image]