# cookie not stored on browser even if response contains 'Set-Cookie' header for ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, setcookie, jquery-cookie

cookie not stored on browser even if response contains 'Set-Cookie' header for ajax request.

Request code:

```
function hitLogin(){
        var loginUrl = "http://myapp:8080/login";

        var geturl;
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url : loginUrl,
            data:   {
            user : "user1",
            password : "encryptedPassword"              
            },              
            headers: {
                "credentials": 'include',
                "withCredentials" : true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest",
                "Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Accept":"text/plain",
            },              

            success : function(data)
            {                   
                alert("Ajax request data: "+data);
            },
            error: function( xhr, status, error ) 
            {
                alert("Ajax request error: "+status ); 
            }
        }); 
        }
```

Response headers received  :

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,accept,content-type,Cookie
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://myapp2.com:7011
>
> Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
>
> Content-Encoding:gzip
>
> Content-Type:text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
>
> Date:Wed, 06 Jun 2018 15:10:09 GMT
>
> Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
>
> Set-Cookie:MYCOOKIE=62lml5_S7qS31KaFDg-SH-e8Ds5FPjljCIHzfmhxMAr8Fdrqr6fHLjI7s2XPAO2P3tNFLNLS1_fgvDXF4pLmfg#1s1S1#normal-false;
>   Path=/; HttpOnly
>
> Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>
> Vary:Accept-Encoding
>
> withCredentials:true

I can see the cookie stored in browser when same url hit from browser, but in case of ajax request, its not stored.
Hence unable to send subsequent requests, which excepts this cookie.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending `withCredentials: true` as an HTTP header, which does nothing useful.  You should instead set it as an [XHR field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).  In jQuery, you can do that like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: loginUrl,
    data: { /* request parameters here */ },
    headers: { /* custom HTTP headers here, if you need any */ },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true,
    },
    /* other AJAX settings here */
})
```

Also, all the other custom HTTP headers you're sending are actually useless, too:

- `credentials: include` is neither a valid HTTP header, an XHR field nor a [jQuery AJAX setting](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  Instead, it appears to be the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) equivalent of jQuery's `withCredentials: true`.  In any case, it's useless here.
- `crossDomain` is also not an HTTP header.  It *can* be used as a jQuery AJAX setting (i.e. *outside* the `headers` object) to force jQuery to treat the request as cross-domain even if the target URL appears to match the domain of the current page.  In your case, it's also useless.
- The `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` HTTP header is automatically added by jQuery, so specifying it as a custom header is 100% redundant.
- There is no need to explicitly send an HTTP `Content-Type` header, since jQuery will automatically generate one.  If you wish to specify which content type jQuery should use for the request, you should do so using the `contentType` setting *outside* `headers`.  In any case, the one you've specified is the default.
- Similarly, instead of sending a custom HTTP `Accepts` header, you should use the jQuery `$.ajax()` settings `accepts` and/or `dataType` to control which content types jQuery will accept in the response.  And usually you won't need to, since the default values used by jQuery are fine unless your server is misconfigured and sends the wrong content type.

Comment: Yes.some header might not be useful, but my main concern is cookie not stored on browser. do we need any explicit handling/header?

Comment: @AmM: No, the `withCredentials: true` XHR field is all that should be needed. It just has to be in the right place, i.e. in `xhrFields`, not in `headers`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned this was the case of CORS and hence jquery request was not able set cookie.

[Set-Cookie on Browser with Ajax Request via CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221722/set-cookie-on-browser-with-ajax-request-via-cors)

Helped to find cause and was able to store cookie with XMLHttpRequest with **withCredentials** set to **true**