# Not Receiving Set-Cookie Header with axios post request

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

I have a PHP Script which successfully returns some simple Headers as well as a set-cookie header if called directly in the browser (or by postman). I can read the response-headers like that from chrome devTools. But as soon as I call it by Axios, the set-cookie header doesn't show up and there's no cookie saved in the browser.

I tried diffrent things like changing the response-headers server-side and using "withCredentials: true" with axios, but nothing worked. I don't even get an error or any cors-related problems.

PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 99999999");
setcookie("TestCookie", "Testing", time() + 3600, "/", "localhost", 0);
die();
```

JS:

```
Vue.prototype.$http = axios.create({
    baseURL: XYZ,
    withCredentials: true
})
```

So my first question is why does the header appear when calling the php script directly? And how can I archive to get the header through axios too?

Comment: Have you made sure it’s not simply due to browser settings that block 3rd-party cookies? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16634941/10955263

Comment: Well I tried to call the Script directly with the same browser and it worked. Or does axios block something with a request? Just checked regarding your link: Chrome is not blocking third-party cookies too

Comment: _“Well I tried to call the Script directly with the same browser and it worked”_ - if you call it directly, it isn’t 3rd-party …

Comment: Sorry, just updated my comment. I'm not blocking third-party cookies

Answer (score 7):

probably cookie is 'httpOnly', which means client side javascript can not read it.
Therefore it is not showing in chrome cookie section.
test the same request in mozilla, header will show up.

Comment: I created a standalone command line script using axios and I also don't receive the 'Set-Cookie' in the headers. The same post request using curl does show the Set-Cookie value in the headers. Postman also receives the Set-Cookie header. I tried with javascript Fetch which also does not show the header. This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 5):

This may not apply to your situation, but I had the same problem using axios in this standalone nodejs script.

```
const config = {
    url: 'https://remote.url/login',
    method: 'post',        
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data: qs.stringify({
        'email': username,
        'password': pwd
    })
}

axios(config).then(res => {
    console.log(res.headers);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

This returned http status 200 without `set-cookie` in the headers. With curl the header was correctly retrieved, but the status code was 302

After adding the following config options to axios:

```
maxRedirects: 0,
validateStatus: function (status) {
    return status <= 302; // Reject only if the status code is greater than 302
  },
```

I received the `set-cookie` in axios in the response.header.

```
{
  server: 'nginx/1.16.1',
  date: 'Fri, 27 Dec 2019 16:03:16 GMT',
  'content-length': '74',
  connection: 'close',
  location: '/',
  'set-cookie': [
    'cookiename=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; path=/; expires=Sat, 26-Dec-2020 16:03:16 GMT'
  ],
  status: '302',
  'x-frame-options': 'DENY'
}
```

Without `maxRedirects: 0` I received the html of the homepage of the remote url I used.

Without `validateStatus` I received the `set-cookie` header in the `err.response.headers` object.

Comment: This worked for me as well. THANK YOU. 3 hours of my life...

```
maxRedirects: 0,
validateStatus: function (status) {
    return status <= 302; // Reject only if the status code is greater than 302
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the network panel showed that the response had the 'Set-Cookie' header, but in axios the header wouldn't show up, and the cookie was being set.

For me, the resolution was setting the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

Explanation:

From [this comment](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2847#issuecomment-605417894) on an issue in the axios repository I was directed to this [person's notes](https://github.com/chinesedfan/You-Dont-Know-Axios#nightmares-of-headers-cors-cookies-and-auth) which led me to set the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers) -- and now the cookie is properly setting in the client.

So, in Express.js, I had to add the `exposedHeaders` option to my cors middleware:

```
const corsOptions = {
  //To allow requests from client
  origin: [
    "http://localhost:3001",
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://104.142.122.231",
  ],
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
};

...

app.use("/", cors(corsOptions), router);
```

---

It was also important that on the axios side I use the `withCredentials` config in following axios requests that I wanted to include the cookies.

ex/

```
const { data } = await api.get("/workouts", { withCredentials: true });
```

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if you got this to work in a production environment. I have the similar set up with React + Flask and it all works locally (supposedly because cookies are shared between ports????), but once deployed in production, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm... it's a while back now and it was just a side-project of mine, so it's hard to remember. I think I had this stuff deployed, but not in any major way. It's possible that I never did though and it was always just local. Sorry I can't give you a more definitive answer @TheVisionary

Answer (score 1):

For me is working adding {withCredentials: true} like this:

```
axios
.post(url, {
    foo: foo,
    baz: baz,
    }, {withCredentials: true})
.then(.............
```