# Laravel 8.x Session disappear

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a newly installed laravel application (version 8.36.2) and the session storing is not working, is it a release issue?

I made my code step-by-step by the laravel documentation, and the stored session is lost, if i open a new route. For example.:

My base controller.:

```
    public function setSession(Request $req)
    {
        $req->session()->put('name', 'Jennifer');
        echo "Saved";
    }

    public function getSession(Request $req)
    {
        if ($req->session()->has('name')) {
            echo $req->session()->get('name');
        } else {
            echo "Empty the session";
        }
    }
```

My web.php

```
Route::get('set-session', [LoginController::class, 'setSession'])->name('session.set');
Route::get('get-session', [LoginController::class, 'getSession'])->name('session.get');
```

The storing is working, so if i dd() the session after the setSession() I can see the name property, but, if I open the /get-session route, the name session property is null.

I also tryed with the session(['name' => Jennifer]) facade, but it also doesn't work.

Can someone help me, why?

Comment: I created a new laravel project and copy and pasted your code and it worked properly, I saw "Jennifer" when I visited get-session.

Comment: Good to hear that. Thank you, that you try it. According to them, definitely some environmental setting is wrong on my computer. 
I will continue the investigation because the Authentatication also doen't work.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63760186/1561929

Comment: unfortunately doen't work. I think the problem, that on every request new session file generated under storage/framework/sessions. So If i refresh the /get-session page 5 time, 5 different session file apper. This is not normal operation, right?

Comment: Finally I find the problem. On the session.php the domain have to be NULL or different than the APP_URL, because of if there is same, the session doen't work. Very-very thank you for your support.